# Empty partition advice

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I need some help. I've been looking around the net and I can't find the answer to help me out specifically.

I dual-booted Ubuntu with Windows 7 on the HD. I ran out of space in Ubuntu and decided I wanted more. I shrank my Windows partition. I now have an empty 50GB partition available. My problem is, I ran GParted and the extended partition containing Ubuntu is all in the left. Windows is in the middle. The empty space is to the right.

Should I move the Windows to the left and merge the extended with the empty space? Or make a new partition on the empty space for Ubuntu to access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure if you installed the grub to the mbr or the root of the Linux partition. If you did install it to the mbr, you can move the Linux partition and merge it with the new space. If the grub is on the Linux root partition use my second suggestion to avoid the headaches of adding a partition back to grub once the move is finished.

A second suggestion would be to use the new empty partition for Ubuntu as that would answer your first problem of not enough space, and you could make it accessible from windows as a file or document partition.

I hope this helps

---

Installing Ubuntu reference

[How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu)

[Illustrative guide of Dual Booting](http://members.iinet.net.au/~herman546/p22.html)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks!  The second choice sounds way better. That's what I thought would be better. but.. If I just make it a New partition.. how can I use it in Ubuntu?? Do I just say.. save this file or whatever in that partition??

Comment: It would be like you saving a file in Drive:D, drive:E and so on. This link should help quite a bit: [link](http://lifehacker.com/5702815/the-complete-guide-to-sharing-your-data-across-multiple-operating-systems)